# WMV video, broken

Tags: wmv

Unexpectedly I have opened video file which I've watched before without any troubles and it appeared to be corrupted. Here an image:

[image]

Update: I try to play it with Video Media Player 12 on Windows 7 64bit. With VLC player I can open it without any problem.

Comment: Essential information is missing. What is the application, does it play on other apps, systems.

Comment: Hi @RomanR. The application is windows media player 12 on Windows 7 64bit, the video works fine with vlc player, but I need WMP due to ability to play at different speed. Thank you.

Comment: I'm wondering is WMP is using some kind of video card accelerated rendering and VLC isn't. Might also be codec related, since VLC uses its own codecs

Comment: Yes, WMP uses hardware acceleration for WM files, try to turn it off via menu Tools, Options, page Performance, check box with "Acceleration..." at the bottom.